# asp.net jquery fancybox -> Close fancybox via codebehind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox, code-behind

Ok, so I have seen this solution to closing a fancybox via a button click. :

$.fancybox.close();

Is there a way that any one is aware of that a fancybox can be closed from the codebehind.

The only thing I can think of is registering a script, because in my situation I need to perform a bunch of logic in my codebehind upon a button click event and then once that has finished close the fancybox.  I have searched all over and have been unable to find a solution.

If anyone has found a way to do this please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: what about making your codebehind method a web method, calling it via ajax and in the success callback calling the close function of fancybox

Comment: Thanks Richard, I am in a bit of a hurry on this one otherwise I would try that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "" , "$.fancybox.close();", true);
```

Comment: Sorry, this specific application is in vb.net.  Corresponding Code is this. :

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "", "$.fancybox.close();", True)

Comment: I found an answer to my question thanks, can't post it yet due to reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found an answer to my question.  Thanks for the replies.  Royi, I think you were going down the right path but your solution created errors within my application.  This was exactly what I was thinking about doing.  My application stated that it was unable to find the type of fancybox due to some proprietary code in my application I believe.

Here is a solution that I found that worked right off the bat.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1640878.aspx/3/10