# How to close the fancy box after clicking submit button?

Tags: jquery

I am using fancy box script in (Page1.aspx),when you click register link in page1.aspx,
it will open (page2.aspx) in fancy box.

Here in (page2.aspx), after submitting my form here, if i click the Submit button,
it should close the page2.aspx and should open page3.aspx in tab of the browser.

How to do that?  I got a code, it opens `page3.aspx` in new tab but it omits the 
validation in `page2.aspx`.

Here the code:
page1.aspx:

```
 function closeFancyboxAndRedirectToUrl(url) {
            $.fancybox.close();
            window.location = url;`enter code here`
        }
page2.aspx:
<a onclick="parent.closeFancyboxAndRedirectToUrl('Bus_Passanger_Information.aspx');">
    <asp:Button ID="BtnCtn" runat="server" Text="Continue" onclick="Btnctn_click"/></a>
```

Now all i want, the both the validation and `page3.aspx` should open in Button click event.

Need additional information, i am in ready to give.
thanks

Comment: This Past SO post May Help You http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038721/asp-net-jquery-fancybox-close-fancybox-via-codebehind

Comment: No that is not working, i keep some validation there, it should some alert if any fields in missing, then after it should close the fancy box and go to the page3.aspx

Comment: for that you can develop the logic in Code behind first call your validate function from code behind and then fancybox close script

Comment: anyway i solved it myself. thanks for your replaying.

Comment: That's great you found it yourself

Comment: `Thirisangu` can you post the working code

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "close", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>{0}</script>", "parent.$.fancybox.close() ;"));
```